# Getting Python list output into column table instead of row

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I've got some Python source code blocks in my Org mode document and when I print lists as output I get an org table of one row with all elements (regardless of whether I create a session or not):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

For long lists this is inconvenient (also when exporting to LaTeX/PDF, for example). Is there a way to change the output to one column, multiple rows?

I have tried adding `:results list` to the source block header, which sort of gives me what I want. Nevertheless, a table is preferred over a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output a column vector by mapping each list element to a row element of a new list of lists (matrix):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
map( lambda x: [x], mylist )
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
```

Comment: Interestingly, when trying your solution in Python3 it didn't work (the output was `<map object at 0x7fe3b0a36160>`). So I decided to convert your solution to a list comprehension: `[ [x] for x in mylist ]`. This works also in Python3